# Simple Exception Not Running In C++

Tags: c++, exception

In my main function i have coded:

```
    try {
    empty.addItem( );
    throw  50;
} catch(int x ) {
    cout<<"fail "<<x;
}
```

Yet when I run the program, fail 50 is not outputted. What are my errors, and also how would I properly use exceptions?

Comment: Ah I figured it out. Bad function syntax earlier in main that didn't get caught, missing a '}'.

Answer (score 0):

it works in the test program below on linux.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    try {
        throw 50;
    } catch(int x ) {
        cout << "fail " << x << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}

$ g++ throw.cpp 
$ ./a.out
fail 50
```

Are you sure this chunk of code is getting executed in your program?

Comment: Well your chunk worked, could the empty.addItem() be throwing it off? No pun intended.

Comment: Could that be throwing another not "int x" exception? Add a printf("going to throw 50\n"); in your code and see if it gets printed.  Also add } catch(...) {  printf("some other exception..\n); }.  to check any other exception thrown by empty.addItem().

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing obviously wrong with your code. There are two possible reasons I can think of that "fail 50" is not printed:

1. Programme control never actually gets to the`try` block -- double check by putting a print statement inside it, just before the `throw`.
2. `empty.addItem()` is throwing an exception which is not an `int`. You'd most likely notice your programme mysteriously failing with an uncaught exception instead.